# How to make access to web service independent of url?

Tags: web-services, url

Imagine I use a web service, whose url changes occasionally.
Is there a way to make my application independent of the current url of the web service, so that my program automatically accesses the current url of the web service (whatever it may be at the moment)?

In my opinion this is not possible since the url is the unique identifier, but I am not absolutely sure.

Comment: 1) set a fixed "discover" URL where you publish the current URL of the service. 2) Send changes to your clients well in advance. 3) Forward requests from old URL to new URL. Your question has multiple answers depending on context

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... I am the client of the web service though ... Is there a way for me to avoid updating the url time and again?

Comment: I believe no without agree with the server part for a solution